# how to display image on circular image on google map in android

Tags: android

```
private Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
     final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
      bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
     final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

     final int color = Color.RED;
     final Paint paint = new Paint();
     final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
     final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

     paint.setAntiAlias(true);
     canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
     paint.setColor(color);
     canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);

     paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
     canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

     bitmap.recycle();

     return output;
    }
```

here is my code for draw my Location on Google map :

```
public void drawMyLocation() {
        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
        String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + "/LociiImages/" + member_id + ".jpg";
        BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromPath(imagePath);

    //  getCircleBitmap(icon);

        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            double mylat = gps.getLatitude();
            double mylong = gps.getLongitude();
            LatLng myPoint = new LatLng(mylat, mylong);
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
            marker.position(myPoint);
            marker.title("You");
            marker.snippet("You are here.");
            marker.icon(icon);
            map.addMarker(marker);


            // // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myPoint, 15));
            //
            // // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
            //

        }
    }
```

Currently I am to displaying an Image on `GoogleMaps` instead of marker but its displaying a Rectangular image. I want display it in circular shapre, I have written a method  for displaying circular image, but I am not able to call this on `GoogleMaps` for displaying image as circular shape in android.

Please tell me where am doing wrong .

Comment: BitmapDescriptor icon =  BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap (getCircleBitmap(yourBitmap))

Comment: what will be yourBitmap ?  @Murtaza Hussain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);



    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromBitmap(getCircleBitmap(bitmap));
```

Replace this Code and Enjoy!!!!